# C# ¿Cómo creo una interfaz genérica que convierta de un tipo a otro y vicecersa?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código pero me marca error, quiero que la interfaz pueda convertir de un objeto a otro:

```
interface IConverterModel<db, model>
{
    db ConvertModelToDb(model); //Error
    model ConvertDbToModel(db); //Error
}
```

Comment: Creo que falta algo mas de información en tu pregunta. Yo te recomendaría editarla y, a ser posible, crear un [mcve] que explique mejor cual es el problema que intentas resolver.

Comment: En los dos métodos que estás definiendo te falta poner el parámetro adecuadamente: db ConvertModelToDb(model m);  en este caso, model es el tipo de dato del parámetro, pero también debes indicar el nombre del parámetro (m en este caso). Otra cosa, te recomiendo bastante que sigas los lineamientos de nombres en c#, usa mayúsculas para los nombres de tipo, incluyendo los tipos genéricos, porque así vomo lo tienes puede llegar a confundir.